# How to add to top of collapsed header tree?

Tags: org-mode

Is there any way to default adding text to the top (rather than bottom) of a collapsed header tree?

Say I have these headers

```
* Main header
** Notes
*** Notes sub-section 1
** Subheader 2
*** Subheader 2.1
```

And collapsed they appear

```
* Main header
** Notes...
** Subheader 2...
```

If I add text to a collapsed tree:

```
* Main header
** Notes...
<return> text added here ->
** Subheader 2...
```

Current result:

```
* Main header
** Notes
*** Note sub-section 1
text added here
** Subheader 2...
```

Desired result:

```
* Main header
** Notes
text added here
*** Note sub-section 1
** Subheader 2...
```

Comment: Just go to the front of the ellipsis ... and press enter. The text you enter afterwards is inserted below "Notes". (As a side-effect it reveals the header.)